# Ahk script and C++ communication

Tags: c++, dll, autohotkey

I wish to use the functions of autohotkey within a C++ program.
I am currently running my scripts triggered by the c++ program- I just run them as a .bat file. This works well but the problem is that I cannot return values from the script to the c++ program.

I wish to be able to read the position of the mouse from the script and make decisions based upon this in my C++ program. My scripts do quite complex things- so doing this in autohotkey is the best solution for me- I have knowledge of C, but little of C++.

I have read about the Autohotkey .DLL - I know how to trigger it but not how to read values from it. If anyone could instruct me or even post example code of a .dll being loaded and a value sent to a script and a value returned- I would be eternally grateful!!

I have spent hours on this and to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

to return a value, could this possibly work http://www.autohotkey.net/~tinku99/ahkdll/functions/ahkgetvar.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the dll, but you *could* just write your own application in Autohotkey and package it along with your C++.

The communication takes place over a hidden window with an edit control and a button.  You use one application to set text in the edit box, and then to click the submit button.  The other application owns the window can process whatever is put into the edit control - as if you were passing a variable.  Basically, that's it.

Check out this thread where I've explained it in more detail: [How to send a command to a running application via commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074944/how-to-send-a-command-to-a-running-application-via-commandline/8085336#8085336)

Now, that's not quite what you wanted, but the effect is the same, and you already know all the api.